# jqueryUI slider - Use .map and .get() in loop to read all sliders' values into array

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Having difficulty reading into a var the values from all five jQuery UI sliders on the page.

I need some help making this code work. Desired outcome is for Submit button to read all current slider values and display an alert with each slider's ID => value.

<kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gm25R/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<div id="labels"><ul>
    <li>DU:</li>
    <li>GH:</li>
    <li>LG:</li>
    <li>SC:</li>
    <li>VL:</li>
</ul></div><!-- #labels -->
<div id="report">
    <span></span>0<span></span>1<span></span>2<span></span>3<br>
    <div id="du" class="slide"></div>
    <div id="gh" class="slide"></div>
    <div id="lg" class="slide"></div>
    <div id="sc" class="slide"></div>
    <div id="vl" class="slide"></div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="reportSubmit" value="Submit" />
```

**jQuery:**

```
var arrSliders;

$("#report > div").each(function() {
  $( this ).empty().slider({
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 3,
    step: 1,
    animate: true,
    orientation: "horizontal"
  }); //this.empty
}); //.each
$(document).on("click", "#reportSubmit", function() {
    $("#report > div").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        arrSliders = $(".slide").map(function() {
            return {
                id: $this.id,
                value: $this.slider("value")
            };
        }).get();
        for (var index in arrSliders) {
            alert( arrSliders[index] );
        }
    }); //END .each
}); //END #reportSubmit.click()
$("#reportSubmit").button();
```

**CSS:**

```
li{list-style-type:none;margin:23px 0px;}
.slide{width:150px;margin-bottom:25px;margin-top:10px;margin-left:30px;}
#labels{float:left;}
#report{float:left;}
#reportSubmit{position:absolute;top:230px;left:50px;}
span{margin-right:40px;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).on("click", "#reportSubmit", function () {
    var arrSliders = $("#report > div").map(function(){
        return  {
                id: this.id,
                value: $(this).slider("value")
            };
    }).get();

    console.log(arrSliders)
}); //END #reportSubmit.click()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wB2a3/)